# How do I return the key of a certain value in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array that I am using to display form dropdown options.  I would like to be able to display the key of a specified array element.

```
$options = array(
                    '10' => '10 Results',
                    '15' => '15 Results',
                    '20' => '20 Results',
                    '25' => '25 Results',
                    '30' => '30 Results'
                );
```

If I use

```
$selected = '25';
echo $options[$selected]
```

this of course returns "25 Results".  How would I return the key of that element?

```
key($options)
```

The above would just return the key of the first element of the array.

Comment: PHP's array_search function will do that for you.

Comment: Isn't `$selected` the key?

Comment: @Anthony is right, or you could loop through them yourself with a foreach.  key() will return the key for the current index of the array.

Comment: @hjpotter92 There is so much win in such a short comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since you are defining the key, it's a pretty easy one...

```
echo $selected;
```

Comment: + Smartass, but true :)

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

In this case, you could use

```
 $key = array_search('25 Results',$options)
```

to find the key that matches the value.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use array_flip:

```
$options = array(
                    '10' => '10 Results',
                    '15' => '15 Results',
                    '20' => '20 Results',
                    '25' => '25 Results',
                    '30' => '30 Results'
                );
$reverseoptions = array_flip($options);
```

Then just do `$reverseoptions['30 Results']; //returns 30;`

Limitations exist.  You can only do this with a simple array; it cannot be recursive without doing a little more code to make that happen.
Also, if any values are alike, the later one will replace the first.

```
$test = array('1'=>'apple', '2'=>'pear','3'=>'apple');
$testflip = array_flip($test);
print_r($testflip);
```

//Outputs Array ( [apple] => 3 [pear] => 2 )

I do this often to convert database representations to readable strings.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `array_search` is to use a foreach loop!  This is in case you do **not** know what the key is beforehand.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

You can access the keys of the array and do as you wish with them.  This will come in handy for doing database conversions as you mentioned.